# How to get same results from dart:encrypt package and crypto-js?

Tags: javascript, flutter, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am using `dart > encrypt` package in flutter.
I want to do some encryption-decryption logic in web-worker in flutter-web project. I have tried to use `crypto-js` package and its vanilla JS https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js.

I want to verify the results if same encryption and decryption values appear with same key.

I have gone through some solutions in stackoverflow as well but couldn't find a suitable working which can provide me same generated values.

Following is dart code and its result:

```
    import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
    .
    .
    final key = Key.fromUtf8("VishnuTestKeyIsHereLongValid32Ch");
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    var encrypted = encrypter.encrypt("Vishnu", iv: iv);
    print(encrypted.base64); // prints 8beisXeeEE055QEPq+kumw==
```

I am expecting same value to be decrypted from Crypto-js. https://jsfiddle.net/vcgupta/grkexuwz/4/

```
//html:
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

//js:

var base64Decrypted = '8beisXeeEE055QEPq+kumw=='

var myKey = "VishnuTestKeyIsHereLongValid32Ch"
var result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(base64Decrypted, myKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

console.log(result);
```

I want to same operations alternatively. Encrypt in javascript and decrypt in dart.

Can anybody help me what I am missing in above solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dart/encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#usage) uses CTR mode (aka SIC) and PKCS7 padding by default (i.e. the padding is not implicitly disabled for stream cipher modes). Since you do not specify a mode in the CryptoJS code, the default mode is applied, i.e. CBC (s. [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding)). Thus both codes are incompatible.

Also, in the CryptoJS code, the key must be passed as WordArray (if it is passed as string, a built-in key derivation is used). Additionally, the IV must be passed *explicitly* (as WordArray). In the Dart code a zero IV (16 0x00 values) is applied.

Furthermore, you should use a newer version of CryptoJS (you are running 3.1.2, the current version is 4.1.1).

Overall, decryption with CryptoJS is:

```js
var base64Decrypted = '8beisXeeEE055QEPq+kumw=='
var myKey = "VishnuTestKeyIsHereLongValid32Ch"
var result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                 base64Decrypted, 
                 CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(myKey), 
                 {
                     iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("\0".repeat(16)), // pass IV
                     mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,                      // apply CTR (aka SIC)
                     padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7                   // apply PKCS#7 (CryptoJS default)
                 }
             );

console.log(result.toString());                   // 566973686e75   // padding removed
console.log(result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));  // Vishnu         // Utf-8 decoded
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind that a static IV (like a zero IV) is a vulnerability. Instead, a random IV should be used for each encryption, which is passed along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, usually concatenated (the IV is not secret).

---

**Edit:** Regarding the bug mentioned in the comment which occurs for plaintexts larger than 1 block (16 bytes): Fixed. Additionally added the following test for plaintexts longer than 1 block:

```js
var base64Decrypted = '87a0+WiecyRYz2l3zpRKsWHZyfUbnZ5Ar3nzYokfuD3zN7iV0M2TefRJe4pr4hh+' // from Dart
var myKey = 'VishnuTestKeyIsHereLongValid32Ch'
var result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                 base64Decrypted, 
                 CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(myKey), 
                 {
                     iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('\0'.repeat(16)), // pass IV
                     mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,                      // apply CTR (aka SIC)
                     padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7                   // apply PKCS#7 (CryptoJS default)
                 }
             );

console.log(result.toString());                   // 54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f67   // padding removed
console.log(result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));  // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog                                              // Utf-8 decoded
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Topaco, it works in one way. I have been trying in different way. Encrypting from Javascript and decrypting from dart for large enough text. It is failing with the reason "Invalid or corrupted pad block"

Comment: @Vishnu - There was the following bug in the CryptoJS code of my answer: When the IV is created with `"\0"`, the Utf8 encoder must be used and not the Hex encoder. This is only noticeable with longer plaintexts. Fixed and added a test case for longer ciphertexts (generated with the Dart code) to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco. It works. May be I will post an end-to-end code to help others soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Topaco, his solution worked great.

Here is an encryption-decryption solution compatible to `javascript <-> dart`. Hope it will be helpful for others.

```js
var textToDecrypt = 'Some long test here';

var myKey = "VishnuTestKeyIsHereLongValid32Ch"
var result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
                 textToDecrypt, 
                 CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(myKey), 
                 {
                     iv: CryptoJS.enc. Utf8.parse("\0".repeat(16)),
                     mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
                     padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                 }
             );
var encryptedString = result.toString();
console.log(encryptedString);

result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
                 encryptedString, 
                 CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(myKey), 
                 {
                     iv: CryptoJS.enc. Utf8.parse("\0".repeat(16)),
                     mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR,
                     padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                 }
             );
var decryptedString = result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decryptedString); 
console.log(decryptedString == textToDecrypt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Above code encrypt and decrypt perfectly in JS. Below code for same purpose in dart:

```
 var textToDecrypt = 'Some long test here';

    var myKey = "VishnuTestKeyIsHereLongValid32Ch";

    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key.fromUtf8(myKey)));
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    var encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(textToDecrypt, iv: iv);
    var encryptedString = encrypted.base64;
    print(encryptedString);

    var decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(encryptedString, iv: iv);
    var decryptedString = decrypted.toString();
    print(decryptedString == ContentType.text);
```

The dart code does separately encrypt and decrypts fine. Also it can be done partially in either language.